# Prove that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = I$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Question: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is non-empty and bounded. Assume $I = \inf(A)$. Prove that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = I$.

I thought about (1) using the definitions:
$A$ is bounded $\iff \exists h\in \mathbb{R} : |a|\leq h \; \forall a \in A$ and $I = \inf(A) \iff \forall a \in A, \; I \leq x \text{ and } \forall \varepsilon>0, \; \exists a \in A: x<I+\varepsilon$;

and (2) to define a constant sequence that is constant and only has $I$ in it (if $I \in A$). But idk what to do when $I \notin A$.

and kinda got nowhere in both cases. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: By *limited* do you mean *bounded*?

Comment: @KeeleyHoek yeah

Comment: By the way, if $I\in A$, then your idea to set all $x_n=I$ works. So I'm not sure why you said that you didn't get nowhere in this case, as for this case what you proposed is a correct solution -- good job! On the other hand, we can avoid considering different cases, because the solution proposed in the answer below works regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* If $I = \inf A$ then in particular as you say for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $a_\varepsilon \in A$ such that $a_\varepsilon < I + \varepsilon$. (The only thing boundedness gets us is finiteness of $I$.) Now set $x_n := a_{\frac{1}{n}}$. (Clearly the sequence $(x_n)$ is contained in $A$.) Can you show that it converges (essentially by definition) to $I$?

**Spoiler:** Indeed $x_n \to I$, since by construction $\lvert x_n - I \rvert = x_n - I < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you!! Ps: I didn't get this definition $x_n := a_{\frac{1}{n}}$. Did you mean $x_n := I +\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @geep No, because $I + \frac{1}{n}$ need not be in $A$ (you are probably imagining that $I$ looks like an interval, which is a good toy example but of course not true in general. Instead we know from the definition of the infimum that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $x_n$ such that $x_n < I + \frac{1}{n}$. i.e. At each stage I am picking $x_n$ to be some such element of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, Keeley!! :)